How to detect classes marked with file modifier
In C# 11, the new file type modifier was introduced.
I was looking for a way to detect such non-public type using reflection, however, I have not find any "good" way to do so.
There is no Is… method that would tell if the type is scoped just to a file (in contrast to methods like IsPublic, IsNested, … and their combinations that can pinpoint whether a method is private (~ is nested) or internal (~ not public (but also not nested)), and so on).
Based on what I gathered so far, any file-scoped type:

is not public -> Type.IsNotPublic == true
is not nested -> Type.IsNested* == false
is not "equipped" with any attribute or "base class" or any other construct I can think of
can only be distinguished by runtime type name that has format of roughly
$"<{filename}>{uniqueHexId}__{userTypeName}" [I did not go to IL, just searched net for it]

Thus, I was able to come-up with following regular expressions to determine if a type is file-scoped or not (that is precise enough for me):
[GeneratedRegex("^<[a-zA-Z_]+>[A-F0-9]+__.*$")]
private static partial Regex FileScopeClassNameRegex()

Am I overlooking something or does the current Type model simply lack means to determine this particular scope of a class?
More precisely: Is there any systematic way to detect file-scoped classes in C#?

I played around with code snippet similar to this fiddle.

I think you're going to run into the same roadblock as protected and internal

"does the current Type model simply lack means to determine this particular scope of a class" - Why should it? It's a compile-time attribute. Use of file-scoped types is enforced at compile time. Once compiled, they're normal classes. Their names are unspeakable, but so are iterator and async state machine types and backing fields generated by the compiler. File-scoped types are not special to the runtime so there's no reflection metadata for it.

Yes, you could use a regex to heuristically detect a file-scoped type, but it relies on an implementation detail that could change. Decompilation, obviously, would need to detect this so it could apply the file modifier to the decompiled class (although the original name is lost so it would still be making one up). I won't say that that's the only use case, but I'm having difficulty thinking of any others. Out of curiosity, why do you need to know this? Or is this just for your own curiosity?

It is both curiosity and a somewhat obscure use case: Instead of writing an analyzer to push a certain style of/requirement for placing public and non-public classes within each assembly of a solution (that multiple people work on), I temporarily opted for a test enforcing the non-standard rules (to balance convenience and cost of the experiment).

An analyzer would be the proper way to go because it runs at compile time when the file modifier has been parsed by the compiler but the class hasn't yet been transformed.

File-scoped types are primarily intended for use by Source Generators so that a generated class name doesn't conflict with your own (or that of another source generator).  There's no way to distinguish a file-scoped class created by a source generator vs. one you wrote once compilation is completed, but you can do so at compile time (the file has either a .g.cs extension or a header with <auto-generated> so the compiler knows it's generated and surfaces that information). An analyzer can skip analysis of generated code.

That allows yout to use source generators that generate file-scoped types (like GeneratedRegex does) but enforce a policy of not using them in your own code (I assume that's what you're trying to do; you were vague about what "style" you were actually trying to enforce).

I did not want to sidetrack too much as the purpose is not particularly relevant to the question (thus I was vague). It is a good point about code generators, yet I'm facing the opposite problem: file-scoped classes are marked by the test as not permissible while they should be allowed at the given place.
If you were more interested in the purpose behind the use-case, feel free to create an issue in this repository.
